# Using python to connect sockets on 2 different machines

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, websocket, server

Connecting 2 Pcs with sockets in python just wont work

here is the code for the server

```py
import socket
host_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_socket.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 9999))
host_socket.listen(5)

while True:
    client, address = host_socket.accept()
    print(f"Connection to {address} established")
    print(client)
    client.send(bytes("cheese", 'utf-8'))
```

and the code for the client

```py
import socket
print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
client_socket = socket.create_connection(('226.225.58.64', 9999))
print("Connected with the server on port 5000")
while True:
    try:
        message = client_socket.recv(4096)
    except ConnectionResetError:
        print("Connection closed by the server")
    except TimeoutError:
        pass
```

Additional information- We both are running python 3.9 on 2 PCs connected to wifi, assume random ip 226.225.58.64 is his ip, which is running server.py both are on the latest version of pycharm community and using its terminal

Comment: Please define *"didn't work"*. Did they connect? Did you try debugging? What errors were there? Why have you tagged `websocket`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with receiving the message. The message is being sent correctly but you did not decode the message and did not print it as well.

```
while True:
    try:
        message = client_socket.recv(4096)
        message = message.decode("utf-8")#since you sent it in utf-8 encoding, you have to decode it in utf-8 only
        print(message)
```

use this code and check if it works for you.